# High Score Board for Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a high score system inside of my game, I don't know any sql, so I can't write it that way. So I was wandering what would be the best and simplest way to use a tab layout to display a global high score on one and local high score on the other. The scores would be taken from the game activity which uses a surfaceview and be displayed on the high score screen activity. If I need sql to make a global high score I will not use it, if I can at least do the local high score that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides SQLite, Android offers several other persistent data methods: shared preferences, internal storage, external (sdcard) storage, and network connections to a server. (See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for details.) For device-local data, it sounds like shared preferences would be pretty easy. If you want global high scores to include data from other devices, you'll probably have to set up a central server somewhere to keep the data.

Comment: If I use the shared preferences will it be accessible between the 2 activities.

Comment: All activities in the same app can access the same shared preferences. That's what the "shared" means. :)

Comment: Shared preferences can be accessed by 2 or more activities belonging to the same application. But, it can't be shared between 2 different applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Swarm's Leaderboard](http://swarmconnect.com/leaderboards) system, which provides pretty much exactly what you're looking for, with almost no effort (pseudocode: .submitScore(1000) and .showScores()).

Comment: The other cool thing about Swarm is that its leaderboards are global, so players from around the world can compete against one another.  On top of that, if the user gets a new phone, they'll still be able to carry their scores forward with them to new devices.